# Views two content type relations

Tags: views

I have two content types.
1. Referrals: Name, other info type fields
2. Referral semesters: start date, end date

I want to list all referral semesters out while counting the number of referrals there were in between the referral semesters start and end time. Looking at the referral creation date.

I've started a view of semesters but see no where I can relate it to referrals in the relationship area.

example:
Spring 2016: 17
Summer 2016 : 22

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use the entity reference view module. I'm importing 1500 nodes and I'd have to go assign each referral to a semester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the entity reference view may help you in this case.

Ref: http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/entity-reference-view-widget

Comment: Without a relationship between 2 different contenttypes, I'm not sure how to establish a join. But you know your content well. So, if there is any join possible, you can add filter criteria in the view.